# .net6 with EF: Sudden OutOfMemory Exception when running tests

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-6.0

The project has a lot of migrations (380 to be exact) and 3360 Unit Tests. Suddenly, after creating one more migration, all UnitTests suddenly fail, throwing an Exception.

```
System.OutOfMemoryException : Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

with the following stackTrace:

```
RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<CreateTestClass>b__0() line 42
ReflectionAbstractionExtensions.CreateTestClass(ITest test, Type testClassType, Object[] constructorArguments, IMessageBus messageBus, ExecutionTimer timer, CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource) line 42
```

This does not just happen when running all the tests, but even when running a single test, it will always fail with the same error. When I remove the new migration, it works. When I add even an empty new migration (where up() and down() are empty) it throws the OutOfMemory Error.

When I right-click a test and call "debug", it runs without the error. So I do not even know how to debug the problem.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem?

Edit:

I added a IDesignTimeDbContextFactory and now the error has changed slightly: when I run the tests now, I get the following:

```
Catastrophic failure: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.get_ExportedTypes()
   at Xunit.Sdk.ReflectionAssemblyInfo.GetTypes(Boolean includePrivateTypes) in /_/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/Reflection/ReflectionAssemblyInfo.cs:line 80
   at Xunit.Sdk.TestCollectionFactoryHelper.GetTestCollectionDefinitions(IAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, IMessageSink diagnosticMessageSink) in /_/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/Frameworks/TestCollectionFactoryHelper.cs:line 22
   at Xunit.Sdk.CollectionPerClassTestCollectionFactory..ctor(ITestAssembly testAssembly, IMessageSink diagnosticMessageSink) in /_/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/Frameworks/CollectionPerClassTestCollectionFactory.cs:line 27
   at Xunit.Sdk.ExtensibilityPointFactory.GetXunitTestCollectionFactory(IMessageSink diagnosticMessageSink, IAttributeInfo collectionBehaviorAttribute, ITestAssembly testAssembly) in /_/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/ExtensibilityPointFactory.cs:line 239
   at Xunit.Sdk.XunitTestFrameworkDiscoverer..ctor(IAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, ISourceInformationProvider sourceProvider, IMessageSink diagnosticMessageSink, IXunitTestCollectionFactory collectionFactory) in /_/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/Frameworks/XunitTestFrameworkDiscoverer.cs:line 45
   at Xunit.Sdk.XunitTestFramework.CreateDiscoverer(IAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo) in /_/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/Frameworks/XunitTestFramework.cs:line 21
   at Xunit.Sdk.TestFramework.GetDiscoverer(IAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo) in /_/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/Frameworks/TestFramework.cs:line 71
   at Xunit.Sdk.TestFrameworkProxy.GetDiscoverer(IAssemblyInfo assembly) in /_/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/Frameworks/TestFrameworkProxy.cs:line 67
   at Xunit.Xunit2Discoverer..ctor(AppDomainSupport appDomainSupport, ISourceInformationProvider sourceInformationProvider, IAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String assemblyFileName, String xunitExecutionAssemblyPath, String configFileName, Boolean shadowCopy, String shadowCopyFolder, IMessageSink diagnosticMessageSink, Boolean verifyAssembliesOnDisk) in /_/src/xunit.runner.utility/Frameworks/v2/Xunit2Discoverer.cs:line 106
   at Xunit.Xunit2Discoverer..ctor(AppDomainSupport appDomainSupport, ISourceInformationProvider sourceInformationProvider, String assemblyFileName, String configFileName, Boolean shadowCopy, String shadowCopyFolder, IMessageSink diagnosticMessageSink, Boolean verifyAssembliesOnDisk) in /_/src/xunit.runner.utility/Frameworks/v2/Xunit2Discoverer.cs:line 62
   at Xunit.Xunit2..ctor(AppDomainSupport appDomainSupport, ISourceInformationProvider sourceInformationProvider, String assemblyFileName, String configFileName, Boolean shadowCopy, String shadowCopyFolder, IMessageSink diagnosticMessageSink, Boolean verifyTestAssemblyExists) in /_/src/xunit.runner.utility/Frameworks/v2/Xunit2.cs:line 41
   at Xunit.XunitFrontController.CreateInnerController() in /_/src/xunit.runner.utility/Frameworks/XunitFrontController.cs:line 144
   at Xunit.XunitFrontController.EnsureInitialized() in /_/src/xunit.runner.utility/Frameworks/XunitFrontController.cs:line 163
   at Xunit.Runner.VisualStudio.VsTestRunner.RunTestsInAssembly(IRunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle, LoggerHelper logger, TestPlatformContext testPlatformContext, RunSettings runSettings, IMessageSinkWithTypes reporterMessageHandler, AssemblyRunInfo runInfo) in /_/src/xunit.runner.visualstudio/VsTestRunner.cs:line 617
```

Comment: We need much more information here. What does the migration do? How many migrations do you already have? What is the full stack trace? etc. etc.

Comment: @DavidG even an empty migration created the problem, I tried it. I have 380 migrations so far and I edited the post to add the stack trace

Comment: How do you run the tests when they fail? What happens if you run from the command line (e.g. `dotnet test`)? What happens if you force it to run in 64bit with `dotnet test  -- RunConfiguration.TargetPlatform="x64"`?

Comment: @DavidG I run the tests via Visual Studio - "run tests". But via console and with TargetPlatform x64 it fails as well

Comment: What if you try adding one more migration - does adding the migration work? Have you tried also updating the database?

Comment: @GuruStron adding another migration works, as in there are no errors - and updating the database works as well. only the tests keep failing

Answer (score 1):

**OutOfMemoryException**

This error maybe occurring because the computer in use is running out of physical RAM memory and is unable to allocate the necessary RAM to complete the task.

Ways I would try to solve this is by closing background applications, close them through task manager. To open click windows key type in task manager. Click on the memory Colum, this will sort buy highest to lowest memory consumption. End task of the programs you dont need example, chrome or a internet browser.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! But it happens on various computers, its not limited to a single PC

Comment: Do you know how much memory these computers have?

Comment: AFAIK OOM can happen not only due to the running out of physical RAM (fragmentation of process memory can be a factor for example).

Comment: Agree with Guru here. OOM exceptions are almost never triggered by actually running out of physical RAM.